# Javascript function to check the username and password fields and if they are not completed accordingly to stop

Tags: javascript, php, submit, registration

I've just started learning PHP and my teacher recommended I use JS to check the input fields for acording lentgh. 
And if the fields are matching specifications to continue with the registration
How do I stop the php from running if RegistrationValidation() returns false ?

Submit button

```
<input type="button" name="Register" value="Register"     onclick="RegistrationValidation()">
```

Registering the new user

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {
include 'SQL.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
NewUser($username, $password);
} else
echo '';
?>
```

Javascript function

```
function RegistrationValidation() {
var username = document.getElementById('username');
var password = document.getElementById('password');
var usererror = document.getElementById('usererror');
var passerror = document.getElementById('passerror');
var registration = document.getElementById('registrationCheck');
var username_check = true;
var password_check = true;

if (username.value.length < 6) {
    var username_check = false;
    usererror.innerHTML = 'Username must have at least 6 characters.';
} else {
    usererror.innerHTML = '';

}


if (password.value.length < 6) {
    var password_check = false;
    passerror.innerHTML = 'Password must have at least 6 characters.';
} else {
    passerror.innerHTML = '';

}

if (username_check == true && password_check == true) {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
} else {
    return false;
    registration.innerHTML = 'Retype username and password';
}
}

//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns false if the validation failed. So you can simply add an `onsubmit` handler to the form, using your function as the handler.

```
// put this before the close </body> tag or wrap it in window.onload = function(){ }
document.getElementById("yourform").onsubmit = RegistrationValidation;
```

This is better than using a click event on the button because the `onsubmit` handles other situations, such as the form being submitted via the enter key.

Remember you still need to do the same validation on the PHP side, because the JavaScript validation can easily be circumvented.

Comment: If I understand correctly the onsubmit handler should look like:
`code` <form method='' action='' onsubmit='RegistrationValidation()'></form>   `code` ?

Comment: That's using the inline event, so you will need to change to `<form method='' action='' onsubmit='return RegistrationValidation()'></form>` (I added `return`). The code in the answer is unobtrusive JavaScript (no inline JS).

Comment: Both methods are working perfectly , thank you for your patience and insight.